# How to get and display value of field gender in form (Reactjs)

Tags: reactjs

I have problem need to support!
I want to get and display value field gender when on click button update. Now, That field not display value.

This is functions and setState

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image: This is code render html of field gender. Value 1 and 0 be saved in database.]
[image: This is form student]

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question  . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

To display the active radio button, you should use `checked={gender === 1}` and `checked={gender === 2}` to the radio buttons to mark it checked based on the current state of gender.